# How to configure rsyslog template for Exception error for remote logging?

Tags: json, logstash, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslog to ship logs to a remote Logstash server, and the Logstash on that service expects input data in a json format. How can I configure an rsyslog template to json-ify a exception. For example, I want to send the following exception as a single message.

```
2017-02-08 21:59:51,727 ERROR :localhost-startStop-1 [jdbc.sqlonly]  1. PreparedStatement.executeBatch() batching 1 statements:
1:  insert into CR_CLUSTER_REGISTRY (Cluster_Name, Url, Update_Dttm, Node_Id) values ('customer', 'rmi://ip-10-53-123.123.eu-west-1.compute.internal:1199/2', '02/08/2017 21:59:51.639', '2')

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.35] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:148)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:137)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeBatchDMLArray(TDPreparedStatement.java:272)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeBatch(TDPreparedStatement.java:2584)
        at com.teradata.tal.qes.StatementProxy.executeBatch(StatementProxy.java:186)
        at net.sf.log4jdbc.StatementSpy.executeBatch(StatementSpy.java:539)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
        at com.teradata.tal.common.persistence.dao.SessionWrapper.flush(SessionWrapper.java:920)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.persistence.dao.DaoImpl.save(DaoImpl.java:263)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.service.AbstractService.save(AbstractService.java:509)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.cluster.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:413)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.cluster.NodeConfiguration.initialize(NodeConfiguration.java:182)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.context.Initializer.onApplicationEvent(Initializer.java:73)
        at com.teradata.trm.common.context.Initializer.onApplicationEvent(Initializer.java:30)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.35] [Error -2801] [SQLState 23000] Duplicate unique prime key error in CIM_META.CR_CLUSTER_REGISTRY.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:301)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:114)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:311)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:200)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:137)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.PreparedBatchStatementController.run(PreparedBatchStatementController.java:58)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:387)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.executeBatchDMLArray(TDPreparedStatement.java:252)
        ... 37 more
```

I have the following rsyslog configuration file. The startmsg.regex aims to "flag" the start of a new message when it sees the "YYYY-mm-dd" date format, and until it sees that format, it should treat any text following the date format as part of the current message.

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/usr/share/tomcat/dist/logs/trm-error.log*"
    Facility="local3"
    Tag="trm-error:"
    Severity="error"
    startmsg.regex="^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}"
    escapeLF="on"
)

if $programname == 'trm-error:' then {
    action(
        type="omfwd"
        Target="10.53.234.234"
        Port="5514"
        Protocol="udp"
        template="textLogTemplate"
    )
    stop
}
```

..and the following template.

```
# Template for non json logs, just sends the message wholesale with extra
# # furniture. 
template(name="textLogTemplate" type="list") {
  constant(value="{ ")

  constant(value="\"type\":\"")
  property(name="programname")
  constant(value="\", ")

  constant(value="\"host\":\"")
  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value="\", ")

  constant(value="\"timestamp\":\"")
  property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value="\", ")

  constant(value="\"@version\":\"1\", ")

  constant(value="\"customer\":\"customer\", ")

  constant(value="\"role\":\"app2\", ")

  constant(value="\"sourcefile\":\"")
  property(name="$!metadata!filename")
  constant(value="\", ")

  constant(value="\"message\":\"")
  property(name="rawmsg" format="json")
  constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

However, Logstash complains about a "jsonparseerror" when it tries to parse the log as a json file. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rsyslog configuration files I'm using are correct, that is, Java exception log is indeed wrapped into a valid JSON file. However, Logstash is complaining about a _jsonparsefailure, so this problem is probably related to Logstash Ruby code, and not on the rsyslog side.